iPhone automatically blocking callers
For a while now, my iPhone has been automatically blocking callers without my knowledge. This has caused me to miss important calls. For example, I was wondering why a local PC repair shop was not returning my calls regarding a laptop I sent in for repair. After further investigation, I found the repair shop's number under Blocked Contacts and several voicemails from them under Deleted Messages. I am 100% certain I did not block that number, especially considering that I was expecting a call from them.
While I do have the Silence Unknown Callers option turned on, my understanding is this feature is not supposed to actually block such callers. However, I have manually blocked a lot of spam callers in recent years.
For the record, I am using an iPhone 13 Pro Max with iOS version 17.5.1 currently installed. I get service from Verizon Wireless. They do offer a service called Verizon Call Filter that automatically blocks spam calls, but that requires a separate app, which I do not have installed.
I’m curious if iOS use the Blocked Contacts list to train its spam detection system.
Either way, how can I disable this "feature" and allow calls to come in without being blocked?

I’m seeing this now, too. I’ll edit my answer if I can figure anything else to try since I got this from an auto body shop working on my vehicle. They said it went to my voicemail,  but I never got any voicemail and never got a missed call or missed voicemail. I’m on TMobile in the US. I gave them a backup number same iOS version, same settings and those rang trough with AT&T as a carrier.

I wonder if this is a bug introduced in a recent iOS version.

No, iOS has a block unknown callers feature that should send them to voicemail and show the call in recents.

To turn on Silence Unknown Callers, go to Settings > Phone, then scroll down, tap Silence Unknown Callers, and turn on the feature. Calls from unknown numbers are silenced and sent to your voicemail, and appear in your recent calls list.

It’s up to them to leave a voicemail or not, so you might only see missed calls. I would contact your carrier to understand how they have this set up carrier side and which of their call blocking services are enabled on your device.
Clean up your contacts and watch closely would be my advice.
